# Confgurable Attachments

Tags: attachment, configuration

**Scenario:**

I want the attachments object to take only certain types of attachments. For example lets say 'pdf, .html, .doc' only. I am well aware if I write a Visualforce page and an apex class I can configure this in `<apex:inputfile>`. Can this be achieved by without writing any piece of code? This has to be totally configurable i.e. giving the manager full rights to choose which attachment formats should work.

I have tried to find but haven't found anything useful so far. Has anyone worked this around?

**Rationale behind no code:**
The solution manager will be a non-programmer so I want to achieve this functionality via configuration and not customization.

Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "Custom Setting" to allow non-coding configuration of which types are allowed. After that, you can create a trigger to determine if the system should allow the upload to continue.

I would recommend a "list" setting, because you can actually get them all in one step. Here's some code:

```
trigger LimitAttachments on Attachment (before insert) {
    Map<String, CustomSetting__c> settings = CustomSetting__c.getAll();
    for(Attachment record: Trigger.new) {
        if(!settings.containsKey(record.contentType)) {
            record.addError('This type of upload is forbidden by the administrator.');
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, there's other ways of going about this. You'll also probably want to write an administration screen to allow administrators to add/remove values from the list without using the setup screen. For example, the page could accept a file upload of a "sample" to allow, so that the correct mime type will automatically be collected without the administrator needing to know if he should be using "text/plain" or "application/vnd.ms-excel".